# Would there be a reason SELECT command is failing?

Tags: php

For some reason my first select command is failing when I try to execute this php code and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. The session starts fine to my knowledge the problem comes when I perform the query selecting from the products table. It's been defined properly and all the values have been intserted properly other wise the site [Products](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis55/rowe_nalani_marissa/CongaMoe/products.php) wouldn't be displaying properly. But I can't add anything to my cart apparently due to the an issue with my select command.

```
<?php

session_start();

$productID = $_POST["productID"];
$cartNumber = $_SESSION["cartNumber"];

require_once('appVars.php');
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
   or die('Could not connect to MySQL server as CIS55Student, cis55 database.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM products_nalanirowe WHERE productID = '$productID'";
$rs = mysqli_connect($dbc, $query) or die('SELECT command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    $productName = $row['productName'];
    $productPrice = $row['productPrice'];

if ($cartNumber <> "") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cart_nalanirowe WHERE cartNumber = '$cartNumber' and ProductID = '$productID'";
    $rs = mysqli_connect($dbc, $query) or die('SELECT command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    if ($num_rows == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO cart_nalanirowe VALUES ('$cartNumber', '$productID', '$productName', CURDATE(), CURTIME() )";
        $rs = mysqli_connect($dbc, $query) or die('INSERT INTO command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
    else {
    }
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cart_nalanirowe ORDER BY cartNumber DESC";
    $rs = mysqli_connect($dbc, $query) or die('SELECT command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
    echo '<br>Selected record from table cart_nalanirowe';
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    $lastCartNumber = $row['cartNumber'];
    $newCartNumber = $lastCartNumber + 1;

    $query = "INSERT INTO cart_nalanirowe VALUES ('$newCartNumber', '$productID', '$productPrice', CURDATE(), CURTIME() )";
    $rs = mysqli_connect($dbc, $query) or die('INSERT INTO command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
    $_SESSION["cartNumber"] = $newCartNumber;
}


    mysqli_close($dbc);
    ob_start();
    header("Location: viewcart.php");


ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I bet your question will have more attention if you narrow your code to the problematic part. Much people will look at your code, think "No way" and on to the next question.

Comment: To execute a query use`mysqli_query($dbc, $query)`, not `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: why are you querying with the "mysqli_connect"

Comment: Also, your code is subject to sql injection attacks. Make sure to use placeholders in your requests and not use plain php string substitution.

Comment: I don't know why I am doing that. That is a good question. Probably best answer I didn't re-read code

Comment: `if ($cartNumber <> "")` What is this...

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER not sure what you mean by sql injection attacks. So not sure what placeholders I'd be using.

Comment: @Diana, for an explanation on sql injection, check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon ; for a quickstart on solutions with mysqli, read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Diana, basically, imagine what happens if someone calls your script with an escaped productId = " '; DELETE FROM cart_nalanirowe WHERE '' = ' "

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to me but okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_query`

```
mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die('SELECT command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Answer (score 1):

Points I wish you looked into first:

- Turn on your error reporting to assist you while at your development level `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`
- Use `mysqli_query($dbc,$query)or die('SELECT command failed. ' . mysqli_error($dbc));` and not `mysqli_connect($dbc,$query);`
- Use **Prepared Statement** for your queries to avoid **SQL INJECTION**

Try these then tell us the lines of your codes with errors and what precise errors they are reporting.

Comment: okay I got the fact I should have used query now. instead of connect. But the other things having little meaning to me. As I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Read up these **Prepare Statement** - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and **error reporting** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php